# Representations of free groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, free-groups

What is known about the representation theory of free groups? In particular, I am interested in character theory and faithful representations. Many results in this theory seem to depend on the group being finite, though it seems many generalizations exist (compact, locally compact, etc).

More concretely, I am interested in whether the following fact translates to free groups. It is known that in free groups, the characters of irreducible representations form a (orthonormal) basis of the vector space of all class functions.

I am looking for any and all references in this area. Thanks!

Comment: A linear representation of $F_2$ is simply a pair of (invertible) $n\times n$ matrices. So up to isomorphism it's the action of $GL_n$ on pairs of invertible matrices.

Comment: Do you mean to say that any pair of matrices in $GL_n$ generates the free group $F_2$? This is false. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860913/linear-representation-of-a-free-group

Comment: @Leo No, that's not what David is saying. Rather, a *homorphism* from $F_2$ to any other group $G$ (in particular to $G=\mathrm{GL}(V)$) is uniquely determined by specifying two elements of $G$, which may be chosen independently. The conjugation action of $G=\mathrm{GL}(V)$ on such pairs has orbits in bijection with isotypes of representations of $F_2$ into $G$.

Comment: Exactly. Since $F_2$ has no relations at all, any two matrices will be a homomorphic image of $F_2$, i.e., a representation. You did not require the representation to be *faithful*. Some of these pairs will be faithful, some won't be.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Is there anything known about faithful representations then?

Comment: You could see e.g. here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124965/are-all-free-groups-linear-i-e-admit-a-faithful-representation-to-gln-k-for

Comment: (Which proves there always exists a faithful linear representation of a free group).

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: The representation of $F_2$ that maps $x$ to the lower triangular matrix $(1,0 // a,1)$ and $y$ to the UT matrix $(1,b//0,1)$ has character $2$ on $x$ and $y$. If $|a|,|b|\geq 2$, this is a faithful representation of $F_2$. This is a good example to get started with. Inequivalent representations of infinite groups can have the same character, but I cannot remember if this is also true for $F_2$.

Comment: My rough paper calculation is that these are all inequivalent, but have different characters.

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment: "they are all inequivalent but have different characters". I would assume this is to be expected, no? That two inequivalent representations have different characters seems natural to me. Perhaps you meant to say they have the same character?

Comment: @Leo:  I believe David meant "all equivalent, but have the same character" since the character is obviously $2$ no matter what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: @Leo No. I meant that they all have different characters. For example, there are infinitely many representations of $\mathbb Z$ that have the same character. For example, send $1$ to $(1,a//0,1)$ for some complex number $a$. Then the character is the constant function $2$, and all such matrices are non-conjugate in $GL_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: I was looking for inequivalent representations of $F_2$ that have the same character. However, the ones I gave all have different characters, and they differ on $xy$ and $xy^2$. I didn't manage to construct faithful characters with the same character for $F_2$.